# Checking delivery status of an SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, fuel, mobileconnect

I'm using the Fuel REST API [postMessageContactSend](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/postMessageContactSend.html) method to send an SMS to a subscriber. I receive the following response for my request:

```
{
   "tokenId": "MTFjQjgzV2VFa2Vlcks5VnZadkhuQTo3OTow"
}
```

I then include this `tokenId` value as a parameter in the [getMessageContactDelivery](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/rest-api/v1/sms/getMessageContactDelivery.html) method to check the delivery status of the SMS. I receive the following response:

```
{  
   "message":"this is the message text",
   "count":1,
   "createDate":"2015-02-16T21:00:29.497",
   "completeDate":"2015-02-16T21:00:31.7",
   "status":"Finished",
   "tracking":[  
      {  
         "mobileNumber":"61402123456",
         "statusCode":"0",
         "message":"Transaction completed"
      }
   ]
}
```

The question is, does `"statusCode":"0"` mean the SMS is delivered? If so, can I assume that if `"status":"Finished"` and `statusCode` > 0, then the SMS could not be delivered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot get whether an SMS message has actually been delivered.  You're essentially seeing whether the hand off to the carrier has been successful, but once the handoff happens, the SFMC has no way of knowing the status of the message.

Comment: Hello Timothy, I'm just trying to use this method as an alternative to manually downloading a [MobileConnect report](https://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/mobileconnect/reviewing_message_activity_in_mobileconnect/). This report shows whether the message was delivered to a mobile device or if it was undelivered (for example, the mobile device has moved out of its service area). Are you saying that this delivery reports are only available by manually downloading reports from MobileConnect?

Comment: Not quite.  We don't actually know for sure, even in that report.  I've asked around to verify.  What is actually happening: we do a call to the carriers, and if there is no error, we assume delivered (which is actually a pretty good assumption).  But absolute verification without assumptions does not exist.

Comment: I've found a list of some [MobileConnect status codes](https://code.exacttarget.com/apis-sdks/mobileconnect-api/sms-status-codes.html) which may be helpful for others when checking the message status.