# SFMC : problem with SMS

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am testing a script for sending SMS.
That testing script retrieves 5 records and send an SMS for each customer.
I have made tests with my co-workers and one of them has not received the SMS and the other 4 have received it correctly.
Apparantly the process has run OK for all.
 I've checked in the _UndeliverableSMS table but there was any information related to my colleague phone number.

Is there any table where I can check if an SMS has been sent correctly or any problem has occurred with a SMS sent?

Comment: Please share the code snippet of your script.

Comment: The script is OK (I'm sure) . I only want to know if there are any tables where is stored the results of a SMS sent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is NOT possible to know the actual delivery status of the SMS or which receivers failed delivery. SFMC will just transfer your message to the carrier and report the status based on that hand-off.

This has been discussed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66538/checking-delivery-status-of-an-sms) as well.